# Clicking to see the dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#services").click( function() {
    $(".subMenus").fadeToggle("slow")
});
});
</script>
```

This is my code. I can hide and show the dropdown(subMenus) with this code. I want to show the dropdown in my first click which it works but I want to go to a link when I clicked to services for the second time. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a perfect way for you

```
$("#services").one('click', function() {
    $(".subMenus").fadeToggle("slow")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this be checking the visibility of your element. When it's not visible show it, when it is move to your link:

```
$("#services").click( function() {
    if($(".subMenus").is(":visible")) 
        window.location = "yourLinkHere";
    else 
       $(".subMenus").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```